for文の結果xとyを配列に入れたい
プログラムの結果を，xとyそれぞれの配列に入れたいのですがどのようにしたらいいでしょうか？
for j in range(10):
    ay = j + 1
    by = ay % 2
    if by == 0:
        y = (ay - 1) * 2.5 - 1.5
        for i in range(6):
            ax = i + 1
            bx = ax % 2
            if bx == 0:
                x = (ax - 1) * 2.5 - 1.5
            elif bx == 1:
                x = (ax - 1) * 2.5
    elif by == 1:
        y = (ay - 1) * 2.5
        for i in range(6):
            ax = i + 1
            bx = ax % 2
            if bx == 0:
                x = (ax - 1) * 2.5 - 1.5
            elif bx == 1:
                x = (ax - 1) * 2.5


xとyそれぞれの配列はどのような結果(次元数・形態や数値の並び方)になることを希望していますか？ 計算の元となるループ変数jとiの値の範囲と順番は決まっているので手計算でも書き出せると思うのですが。 こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問の詳細化を行ってみてください。良い質問をするには？

「配列」とは何のことでしょうか？ リストのことでしょうか？ https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html   そうであれば空のリストを作成してループ内で追加処理していけば良いかと思います。

私はPython初心者です。
全体のアルゴリズムが良く理解できません。
質問の x を含む内側のループは２つとも同じように思えます。
また、x は j の値には関係ないように思えるのでy と同じレベルで１次元にしても良いのではないかと思います。
とりあえず、提供のコードを参考に yを１次元の配列、x を２次元の配列とすると、下記のようにコーディングできます。
y = []
x = []
for j in range(10):
    ay = j + 1
    by = ay % 2
    if by == 0:
        y.append((ay - 1) * 2.5 - 1.5)
        x.append([])
        for i in range(6):
            ax = i + 1
            bx = ax % 2
            if bx == 0:
                x[j].append((ax - 1) * 2.5 - 1.5)
            elif bx == 1:
                x[j].append((ax - 1) * 2.5)
            print(f"  x {j!s},{i!s} {x[j][i]!s}")
    elif by == 1:
        y.append((ay - 1) * 2.5)
        x.append([])
        for i in range(6):
            ax = i + 1
            bx = ax % 2
            if bx == 0:
                x[j].append((ax - 1) * 2.5 - 1.5)
            elif bx == 1:
                x[j].append((ax - 1) * 2.5)
            print(f"  x {j!s},{i!s} {x[j][i]!s}")
    print(f"y {j!s} {y[j]!s}")
print(y)
print(x)
for j in range(len(y)):
    print(f"y {j!s} {y[j]!s}")

for j in range(len(x)):
    for i in range(len(x[j])):
        print(f"  x {j!s},{i!s} {x[j][i]!s}")

[] で配列を作成して、appendで要素を追加します。
最後の print文は参考のために記述しました。
ご参考になれば幸いです。
不明な点があればご連絡ください。
私も勉強になります。
※ループの回数を配列のサイズを使うように修正しました。(2024/5/31)
range(10) ー＞ range(len(x))


xとyそれぞれの配列に入れたい

掲示されているコードに書き間違いがないのであれば、内側のループ(for i in range(6): ...)は byの値(jの値)に関わりがなく全く同じです。また、y に関しては内側のループ内では変更されていないので以下の様になります。
xlist = [x * 2.5 - (1.5 if x % 2 else 0) for _ in range(10) for x in range(6)]
ylist = [y * 2.5 - (1.5 if y % 2 else 0) for y in range(10)]



プログラムの結果を，x と y それぞれの配列に入れたい

オリジナルの記述に以下を適用します。なお，Python 本体にデータ構造として「配列」は用意されていないので，リストで代用しました（[] は空のリスト）。

最初の行に x, y = [], [] を記述

x = ***，y = *** をそれぞれ x.append(***)，y.append(***) に変更


これで実現できますが，式を変形すれば if 文はなくせるので，それも織り込んだ記述例を下記に示します。
x, y = [], []
for j in range(10):
    y.append(j * 2.5 - (j % 2) * 1.5)
    for i in range(6):
        x.append(i * 2.5 - (i % 2) * 1.5)

print(x)
print(y)

